# Quartz job java table name change needed

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz job scheduler in my project. Due to naming convention in particular db , we have to add prefix .

Example all quartz tables start with "qrtz" ,but we need add "acc_qrtz" , if i change the tables names will it works??

Answer (score 4):

You could use JDBCJobStore with the Table Prefix with below propertly.

### Property File: quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = acc_
```

Reference: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html